# Inplace transpose of a matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, transpose

I'm trying a simple intuition to transpose a matrix in place.

I'm trying to swap elements of `matrix[i][j]` and `matrix[j][i]` but it is not working, I'm wondering what is happening behind the scene.

```
class Solution {
    public int[][] transpose(int[][] matrix) {
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++){
                int temp = matrix[i][j];
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
                matrix[j][i] = temp;
            }
        }
        
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

**Output**

For matrix -> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

It is giving output -> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

but the expected output should be -> [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are transposing each pair of elements twice, which puts them back how they were.

One solution would be to change `for(int j = 0;` in the inner loop to `for(int j = i + 1;`.  This would make sure that each pair of elements is only transposed once.

Also be aware that this general solution only works for square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

how about this way?

```java
public int[][] transpose(int[][] matrix) {
    int[][] result = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++){
            result[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This seems to create an awful lot of output!

Comment: Your answer gives a working solution, but can you also explain why this works, and the importance of using a new array to prevent interacting with already moved values. Note that for large arrays this will be a lot less efficient than the other answer

Comment: thanks for your answer @dangerousman, But I don't want to use any extra 2D array, though I already mentioned the inplace transpose.